# Are source IPs included in Linux's Ephemeral Port Uniqueness?

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, ip, tcp

From http://aleccolocco.blogspot.com/2008/11/ephemeral-ports-problem-and-solution.html (2008)

> Linux shares the assigned list of ephemeral ports across all local IPs
>   for unconnected sockets.

Has this changed at any point or is this still the behavior?